# how to disable all refresh events by PHP code?

Tags: php, web

I need disable all refresh events

Example. 
1. F5,
2. Mouse right click option (refresh/reload),
3. CTRL+R,
4. Menu bar -> view -> refresh and
5. URL refresh/reload button

How to disable these all events by using PHP or JS

Comment: This is a job to be done on the client-side. From outside the client, this is exactly the type of things the security features and sandboxing exist for, to prevent malicious documents from hijacking. Disabling/Blocking/Injecting the browser or operating system's event loop could be used to do some nasty things. For example, F5 could be made to in turn send keyboard events back that would launch a program (like WIN+R, then type bad command that could further hijack other files, et cetera). Never cross the line into the client and respect configuration choices the user has made.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Why do you want to do that? You may not interfere with the normal operation of the user's operating system, nor the default behaviour of the browser.
It is possible to block the F5 key but you simply cannot control the refresh button specific to your browsers' toolbar, nor the mouse right-click option.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">

  document.onkeydown = function(ev) {   
  var key;
  ev = ev || event;
  key = ev.keyCode;
  if (key == 116) {
  return false;  // disable F5 key
 }

 </script>
```